# Google analytics user ID - integrated, but how I can see user id?

Tags: google-analytics

I have integrated google analytics user ID, and created the view.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
    ga('set', 'userId', '<?=$_SESSION['user']['email']?>');
<?php } ?>  
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But in anayltics,I don't see their ID, just normal stats

http://awesomescreenshot.com/03d5u9sw4f

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The user id feature in google analytics is for use with internal calculations.

[About the User ID feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en)

> In an Analytics implementation **without** the User ID feature, a unique
>   user is counted each time your content is accessed from a different
>   device and at each new session. For example, a search on a phone one
>   day, purchase on a laptop three days later, and request for customer
>   service on a tablet a month after that is counted as three unique
>   users in a standard Analytics implementation - even if all these
>   actions happen with an account sign-in. While you can collect data
>   about each of these interactions and devices, you can’t determine if
>   any relationships exist. You only see independent data points.
>
> When you **implement** the User ID, you can identify related actions and
>   devices and connect these seemingly independent data points. That same
>   search on a phone, purchase on a laptop, and re-engagement on a tablet
>   that previously looked like three unrelated actions on unrelated
>   devices can now be understood as three related actions on related
>   devices. This gives context to your analysis and so you can get a
>   holistic view of your users and their behaviors.

This is not something that you can see its was already used by google to calculate the data.

If you want to track your user ids you can add them as a custom dimension that you would then be able to analyze on.  However there are some rules and guidelines for doing this. [Universal Analytics usage guidelines](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en)

> Analytics customers are prohibited from sending personal information
>   to Google.
>
> The Analytics terms of service, which all Analytics customers must
>   adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable information (PII)
>   to Analytics (such as names, social security numbers, email addresses,
>   or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular
>   device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an
>   identifier cannot be reset). Your Analytics account could be
>   terminated and your data destroyed if you use any of this information.

Comment: Isn't it now also used in the new User Explorer Report (which seems a privacy nightmare waiting to happen) ? Per the release notes, "Anonymous Client ID and User ID will be surfaced in this report as a part of the release" (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392777?hl=en&ref_topic=6179391)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if more stuff doesn't appear now that they have released v4.